# Bower and GruntJS. Concatenating vendor JavaScript into one file.

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, bower

I'm using Bower and GruntJS to develop a static website. I use Bower to install packages (e.g. jQuery, Bootstrap, some Jquery plug-ins) to a folder called `src/_lib` and then I use `grunt-bowercopy` to copy the scripts I need into a 'vendor' folder. I then use GruntJS to concatenate and then minify the javascript:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  concat: {
    dist: {
      src: ['vendors/*.js', 'js/*.js'],
      dest: 'src/script.js'
    }
  },

  uglify: {
    options: {
      banner: '/*\n <%= pkg.name %> <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %> \n*/\n'
    },
    build: {
      src: 'src/js/script.js',
      dest: 'build/js/script.min.js'
    }
  },
});
```

Do I risk breaking some of the javascript code by putting all the JavaScript into one file?
Is there a way to make GruntJS start with the JQuery in case the other code is dependant on the JQuery?

Comment: You only get the same risks you would get by including them all on the same page. If jQuery has to come first, just make it the first element in your `src` array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to ensure that javascript files are concatenated in the correct order I copied the relevant javascript files from the bower directory into another directory. I used `grunt-bowercopy` to do this. I then used `grunt-contrib-concat`, making sure the order was correct in the `src` array. To test if it worked correctly a put the following snippet into the `src/js/script.js` file:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});
```

The complete gruntfile I used is as follows:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    bowercopy: {
        options: {
            srcPrefix: 'src/_lib'
        },
        test: {
            options: {
              destPrefix: 'test/js',
            },
            files: {
              'jquery.js' : 'jquery/jquery.js',
              'bootstrap.js' : 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js'
            },
        },
    },
    concat: {   
        dist: {
            src: [
                'test/js/jquery.js', 
                'test/js/bootstrap.js',
                'src/js/script.js',
            ],
            dest: 'test/js/scripts.js',
        }
    },
    uglify: {
      options: {
        banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %> <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %> */\n'
      },
      build: {
        src: 'test/js/scripts.js',
        dest: 'build/js/scripts.min.js'
      }
    },    
  });

  // Load the plugins.
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-bowercopy');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');

  // Default tasks.
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['bowercopy', 'concat', 'uglify']);

};
```